# jquery ui draggable: doesn't work in 1.10.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-1.9

After upgrading the jquery ui from 1.10.0 to 1.10.3, the draggable code below doesn't work at all. Any one has come across this? Is it a bug in the latest version or what have been changed?

css,

```
.BR-popup-outer{
    position:absolute; 
    top:0;
    left:0; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    padding:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius: 4px; 
    background: url(../image/trans_black.png);
}

.BR-popup-inner {
    text-align:left; 
    background-color:#ffffff; 
    margin:0px; 
    padding:20px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border:0px solid #999;
    color:#333333;

    cursor:default;
}
```

jquery ui,

```
object_popup.draggable({ 
    cursor: "move",
    handle: ".BR-popup-outer",
    cancel: ".BR-popup-inner"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's bug - Check this out
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9315

That appears only with using UI 1.10.3 and when the scrollbar is not at the very top in Firefox, Opera, IE8.

In Chrome works fine and also with 1.10.2 on other browsers.

The UI dialog demo page has this bug too:

drag the dialog down until appears the scrollbar
scroll down
again drag the dialog down.
dialog goes down with the offset

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9315